# Tokenize string in java using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have input String in following format:

```
"xyz PQ (All) (foo \"(abc\" def) test \"elasticSearch\" (test \"pqr\" stu) "
```

I want to tokenize it such that the string should be split by space excluding double quotes and parentheses, so it should give below result

```
xyz
PQ
All
foo "(abc" def
test
"elasticSearch"
test "pqr" stu
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following regex solves the purpose:

```
(\\([^)]+\\))|([^ \"]*\"[^\"]*\")|([^ ]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

`(\([^)]+\))|([^ ]+)`

Explanations and usage [here](https://www.regex101.com/r/bG2qO2/1).